# How to save multiple form data using one submit button

Tags: jquery, html, jsp, servlets, requestdispatcher

In my jsp page I have two forms.one form action goes to `save_product` servlet and other one is goes to `save_images` servlet. There is  only one submit button. when  click submit button first I want to  save products and then want to save images.

I tried it using jQuery and `Request.getRequestDispatcher(String).forward()` .but it is not succeeded.

This is my jsp:

```
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="formsave1">Save</button>

    <div class=container>
     <div class="panel">
        <form action="../save_product" method="POST"><button type="submit" id="formsave2" ></button> 
    </div>
      <div class="panel">
        <form action="../save_images" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
             <button type="submit" id="formsave3"></button>
</div>
    </div>
```

Product save servlet:

```
req.getRequestDispatcher("save_images").forward(req, resp);
```

jQuery:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
                $(formsave1).on("click", function (e) {
                    alert('CLICKED 1');
                    $('#formsave2').click();
                       alert('CLICKED 2');
                });
```

Comment: you can't forward the request like that. If you want to "forward" the request you need to use `response.sendRedirect`. But you will not be able to use this with POST because it won't retain the parameters... Why not just fix your back end so you only need to call 1 servlet?

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte That's not true, you can forward the request to another servlet including all the POST or GET parameters.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to have any problem, or the given data is insufficient to provide an answer. Keep in mind that if the date is sent via POST `doPost()` will be called in both servlets.

Comment: thanx both of you. req.getRequestDispatcher("save_images").forward(req, resp);  is correct.  it access save_image servlet.

Comment: Ah interesting. Good to know. Thanks for the correction Roshana.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is insufficient to identify the problem completely. I cannot spot the issue.

However, as per your html code I guess that both servlets are in the same package. In that case you may directly call the `doPost()` or `doGet()` methods of `save_images` as they both have `protected` access modifier.

There's no need to use the Requestdispatcher after all.

```
new save_images().doPost(req, resp);
```

Comment: I can not directly call that.I did this.                            
save_images s = new save_images();
s.doPost(req, resp);  is this correct.

Comment: Ohh... Yeah, my bad. It's not static so you'll have to create an object of the class..