# Get error from file uploading

Tags: hibernate, servlets, apache-commons-fileupload, requestdispatcher

I am tring to upload images using image_servlet.
the request is passing from `product` servlet to  `save_images` servlet

```
 req.getRequestDispatcher("save_images").forward(req, resp);
```

**jsp code**

```
<form action="../save_images" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 //img tags in here
</form>
```

but I got this error

> org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$InvalidContentTypeException:
>   the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed
>   stream, content type header is application/x-www-form-urlencoded

I am uploading jpg images.
anyone have an idea above this error.

Comment: Post your jsp form code

Comment: sure. I edited  the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this question is related to the [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50660889/2408342).

If so, you are making a huge mistake. In the previous question you have entered two `<form>`s.

But you submit the first `<form>` which is an *application/x-www-form-urlencorded* type form, and then parse it to the second servlet using the Requestdispatcher. So the error is pretty obvious here.

Remove the second `<form>` and add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the first form.

```
<div class=container>
    <form action="../save_product" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <button type="submit" id="formsave2"></button>
         <div class="panel">
         </div>
         <div class="panel">
             // img tags in here
         </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Remember, the form you are submitting should have the `enctype` mentioned.

Comment: Actually  I can not use single form tag to this stuff. if I use single form tag, the close form tag cannot sync with the open form tag.(<form></form> not sync). that why I using two forms.

Comment: Then make it sync. You can even open the form tag after the body (`<body><form>`) tag and close it before closing the body tag (`</form></body>`).